# What does this technical specification about GSM iPhone mean?

Tags: iphone

This is the text from Wiki on "iPhone 4" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4

> Connectivity:
>
> GSM model:  quad-band GSM/GPRS/EDGE(800, 850, 900, 1,800, 1,900 MHz)
>
> Quad-band UMTS/HSDPA/HSUPA (800, 850, 900, 1,900, 2,100 MHz) (800 MHz
> is not yet officially supported by Apple)

very confused, if Apple does not support 800MHz then why they put the 800 in the specification?

Can someone explain what that technical specification means?

Comment: Where are you getting that Apple doesn't support 800MHz. You give sources against your point but not to support it.

Answer (score 3):

If you keep reading...

[Connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4)

> In contrast to Steve Jobs' announcement at WWDC 2010, recent Federal
> Communications Commission documentation has shown that the iPhone 4
> contains a **penta-band** 3G UMTS antenna, not a quad-band 3G UMTS radio,
> as advertised by Apple.
>
> According to the FCC documentation filed by
> Apple, the radio inside the iPhone 4 **supports 800**, 850, 900, 1,900,
> and 2,100 MHz. The 800 MHz frequency, which is most commonly used in
> Japanese mobile phones, is not advertised as being supported by
> Apple.[51] However, the 800 MHz band is a subset of the 850 MHz band,
> which probably explains why the device is advertised as
> quad-band.[citation needed] The chip-sets were manufactured by
> Skyworks Solutions[52] and Infineon for GSM version.